# How is "return (from tbl in context.[tablename] select tbl)" executed if calling method then does a .Where() on result?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

A method returns the `IQueryable<T>` result of a `from x in context.y select x` query.

The calling method then calls `.Where( a => ...)` on that resultset.

Is the entirety of `x` going to be returned in `IQueryable<T>`, and *then* filtered? Or will LINQ load this lazily, and only once the resultset is iterated, will the actual SQL query be executed (using that `where` condition)?

This is using EntityFramework LINQ to Entities, against a MSSQL database.

Comment: @Shoe: It's not trivial to use the VS debugger to fully answer the OP's question (especially as clarified by Electric Coffee).  That said, monitoring what SQL queries are being fired via SQL Server Profiler is pretty easy.  I would recommend doing this kind of experimentation using LinqPad, which can output the SQL being generated for a given request.

Comment: No, it's not trivial... it's the first thing I tried. I didn't know about LinqPad, that looks really useful. Thanks for the help, Brian.

Comment: @CraigSaboe: Sure.  See [Using LinqPad with Entity Framework](http://www.linqpad.net/entityframework.aspx) for official documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the method returns an `IQueryable<T>`, that's returning the query - not the *results* of the query. So calling `Where` will construct *another* query, applying a filter to the original query... still using expression trees.

So when you then actually start iterating over the results, the whole query will be converted to SQL, including the filter.

If the method had returned an `IEnumerable<T>` instead, then it would still represent the query (rather than the results), but the `Where` call would be using LINQ to Objects - so the filtering would happen in the client rather than in the database.

Comment: Clears it up nicely for me... much appreciated. Still trying to learn the ins/outs of EF.